# Relativistic Corrections to orbital elements

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, celestial-mechanics, post-newtonian

Given a massive compact object $M$ and a smaller object $m$ orbiting it in an elliptical orbit where $M \gg m$, Newtonian gravity describes the orbital elements $(a, e, i, \omega, \Omega, T)$, such as $(a, e)$, as follows:

$$ a = - \frac{\mu}{2E} \, , $$

where $E = \frac{v^2}{2} - \frac{\mu}{r}$, $\mu = G (M + m)$, and $r$ represents the distance between the object with mass $M$ and the one with mass $m$.

The eccentricity $e$ is given by:

$$ e = \left( 1 - \frac{h^{2}}{a \mu} \right)^{1/2} \, , $$

where $h$ denotes the angular momentum.

I read somewhere, for the PPN-first-order corrections, it's stated as follows:

$$\Delta a = \frac{\gamma}{c^2}\frac{\mu}{r} \, , $$

and

$$\Delta e = \left( \frac{h^2}{a \mu} \left( \frac{\beta}{c^2}\frac{\mu}{r}\right) \right)^{1/2} \, .$$

I'm curious about how these corrections are derived. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how other orbital elements might be corrected within the PPN framework. Moreover, I'd like to explore the corrections associated with higher orders. Can you help me, please?

Comment: There's some info on how PPN is applied to Solar System calculations in [The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441](https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-3881/abd414), Ryan S. Park et al (2021).